# I want in arraylist<File> sort....

Tags: java, sorting

i want file sort this source but i can't..

```
ArrayList<File> filelist=new ArrayList<File>();
File topdir=new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
File[] allfile=topdir.listFiles();
for(int a=0; a<allfile.length; a++)
{
filelist.add(allfile[a]);
}
```

ex) filelist = [C:\A.txt , C:\C.txt ,C:\B.txt , C:\E.txt,C:\D.txt ,C:\G.txt,C:\F.txt]
i want file list sort.... 
but i want filelist =[C:\A.txt ,C:\B.txt ,C:\C.txt ,C:\D.txt , C:\E.txt ,C:\F.txt ,C:\G.txt]

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of [`Arrays.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29) or [`Collections.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29)

```
File[] allfile=topdir.listFiles();
Arrays.sort(allfile);
ArrayList<File> filelist=new ArrayList<File>(Arrays.asList(allFile));
```

Or

```
File[] allfile=topdir.listFiles();
ArrayList<File> filelist=new ArrayList<File>(Arrays.asList(allFile));
Collections.sort(filelist);
```

If you want to control the way the sorting is done, you will need to supply a [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) which can be passed to both these methods...